# jquery ui autocomplete - scrollbar does not show on mobile

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the css styling to show the vertical scrollbar for jquery ui autocomplete list as listed in the jquery ui website. I see the scrollbar on desktop but not on mobile. for example I can see the scrollbar on safari on my desktop. but when I try to view using safari on ipad or iphone, it does not show the scrollbar.
any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try: 

.ui-autocomplete
{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: default;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to your answer? It will help the OP and future visitors to understand your solution proposal.

Comment: I found any attempt to scroll triggers a SELECT event on touch devices.